# How to know when activity is paused/resumed from inner view?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

From a view (a custom status bar) I need to know when the activity is paused and resumed. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just create two methods `onResume()` and `onPause()` of your custom `View` (you can call this two methods whatever you want). Then in your activity you will have override `onResume` and `onPause` and call `customView.onResume()` and `customView.onPause()`.

Comment: Don't forget to call super.resume() before your own resume code, and super.pause() after your own pause code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible?

Yes and very easily.

Declare a interface and provide its implementation via your inner view to the outer activity.
Call the respective delegate in the onResume and onPause of activity to notify your inner view.

Simple. Hope this helps :)

Something like this

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public interface ActivityLifeCycleLister{
        onResumeCalled();
    }

    public ActvityLifeCycleLsistener listener;

    public void setActivityLifeCycleListener(ActvityLifeCycleLsistener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(listener != null) {
            listener.onResumeCalled();
        }
    }

    class MyInnerView extends View {

        // Some init method
        void init() {
            MyActivity.setActivityLifeCycleListener(new ActivityLifeCycleListener() {

               void onResumeCalled() {
               // Do whatever here
               }
            });
        }
    } 

}
```

This approach can be used for all the components of your application who wants to listen life cycle events.

Comment: I'm not sure about the need of the interface, can you provide some sample code, just a couple of lines... thanks